# Why do i get an error when the code seems fine?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

This isnt my code but I need to fix it. I get an error saying 'Cannot Update. Database or object is read-only' and it highlights '.Edit'. From what i understand one of the tables are going to be updated if there were changes made in the other table. It doesn't seem to be doing that though. I tried putting rsCH before the .Edit and rsOO as well to see if it would fix the issue but it doesnt.

```
Function DefineOrderChanges()
' this function defines the order changes for any order that is in the query OpenOrdersOnOrderImportFile
' it looks at 6 fields and captures the changes in the Changes file
' need to also develop an order change acknowledgement process.  Send out an email to each primary engineer and
' secondary engineer that is assigned to a project.  Unassigned jobs don't matter???
' there should be an attribute in the Changes table that says each change has been acknowledge done by some new form
' code to follow here.
     ' Detailer/Engineer
     ' Name vs CustName
     ' Description
     ' Order Qty vs OrderQyt
     ' Planned Start Date vs PlannedStartDate
     ' Req'd Release from Engr vs ReqReleaseFromEngr
Dim rsOO As DAO.Recordset ' open orders
Dim rsCH As DAO.Recordset ' order change history
Dim rcOO As Long ' record count in the open order recordset

Set rsOO = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("OpenOrdersOnOrderImportFile")
Set rsCH = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("OrderChanges")
If rsOO.RecordCount = 0 Then
    Set rsOO = Nothing
    Set rsCH = Nothing
    Exit Function
End If

With rsOO
    .MoveLast
    rcOO = .RecordCount
    .MoveFirst
    
    For i = 1 To rcOO
        
        If .Fields("OrdersRawData.Detailer/Engineer") <> .Fields("Orders.Detailer/Engineer") Then
            ' write a record to the change table
            rsCH.AddNew
            rsCH.Fields("Project") = .Fields("Project")
            rsCH.Fields("CustomizedItem") = .Fields("CustomizedItem")
            rsCH.Fields("DateAdded") = Now()
            rsCH.Fields("Field") = "Detailer/Engineer"
            rsCH.Fields("OldValue") = .Fields("Orders.Detailer/Engineer")
            rsCH.Fields("NewValue") = .Fields("OrdersRawData.Detailer/Engineer")
            rsCH.Fields("RequestedBy") = "BAAN"
            If IsNull(.Fields("DateAssigned")) Then rsCH.Fields("ChangeAck") = -1
            rsCH.Update
            ' now make the change to the existing order
            .Edit
            .Fields("Orders.Detailer/Engineer") = .Fields("OrdersRawData.Detailer/Engineer")
            .Update
            
        End If
        If .Fields("Name") <> .Fields("CustName") Then
            ' write a record to the change table
            rsCH.AddNew
            rsCH.Fields("Project") = .Fields("Project")
            rsCH.Fields("CustomizedItem") = .Fields("CustomizedItem")
            rsCH.Fields("DateAdded") = Now()
            rsCH.Fields("Field") = "CustName"
            rsCH.Fields("OldValue") = .Fields("CustName")
            rsCH.Fields("NewValue") = .Fields("Name")
            rsCH.Fields("RequestedBy") = "BAAN"
            If IsNull(.Fields("DateAssigned")) Then rsCH.Fields("ChangeAck") = -1
            rsCH.Update
            ' now make the change to the existing order
            .Edit
            .Fields("CustName") = .Fields("Name")
            .Update
        End If
        If .Fields("OrdersRawData.Description") <> .Fields("Orders.Description") Then
            ' write a record to the change table
            rsCH.AddNew
            rsCH.Fields("Project") = .Fields("Project")
            rsCH.Fields("CustomizedItem") = .Fields("CustomizedItem")
            rsCH.Fields("DateAdded") = Now()
            rsCH.Fields("Field") = "Description"
            rsCH.Fields("OldValue") = .Fields("Orders.Description")
            rsCH.Fields("NewValue") = .Fields("OrdersRawData.Description")
            rsCH.Fields("RequestedBy") = "BAAN"
            If IsNull(.Fields("DateAssigned")) Then rsCH.Fields("ChangeAck") = -1
            rsCH.Update
            ' now make the change to the existing order
            .Edit
            .Fields("Orders.Description") = .Fields("OrdersRawData.Description")
            .Update
        End If
        If .Fields("Order Qty") <> .Fields("OrderQty") Then
            ' write a record to the change table
            rsCH.AddNew
            rsCH.Fields("Project") = .Fields("Project")
            rsCH.Fields("CustomizedItem") = .Fields("CustomizedItem")
            rsCH.Fields("DateAdded") = Now()
            rsCH.Fields("Field") = "OrderQty"
            rsCH.Fields("OldValue") = .Fields("OrderQty")
            rsCH.Fields("NewValue") = .Fields("Order Qty")
            rsCH.Fields("RequestedBy") = "BAAN"
            If IsNull(.Fields("DateAssigned")) Then rsCH.Fields("ChangeAck") = -1
            rsCH.Update
            ' now make the change to the existing order
            .Edit
            .Fields("OrderQty") = .Fields("Order Qty")
            .Update
        End If
        If .Fields("Planned Start Date") <> .Fields("PlannedStartDate") Then
            ' write a record to the change table
            rsCH.AddNew
            rsCH.Fields("Project") = .Fields("Project")
            rsCH.Fields("CustomizedItem") = .Fields("CustomizedItem")
            rsCH.Fields("DateAdded") = Now()
            rsCH.Fields("Field") = "PlannedStartDate"
            rsCH.Fields("OldValue") = .Fields("PlannedStartDate")
            rsCH.Fields("NewValue") = .Fields("Planned Start Date")
            rsCH.Fields("RequestedBy") = "BAAN"
            If IsNull(.Fields("DateAssigned")) Then rsCH.Fields("ChangeAck") = -1
            rsCH.Update
            ' now make the change to the existing order
            .Edit
            .Fields("PlannedStartDate") = .Fields("Planned Start Date")
            .Update
        End If
        If .Fields("Req'd Release from Engr") <> .Fields("ReqReleaseFromEngr") Then
            ' write a record to the change table
            rsCH.AddNew
            rsCH.Fields("Project") = .Fields("Project")
            rsCH.Fields("CustomizedItem") = .Fields("CustomizedItem")
            rsCH.Fields("DateAdded") = Now()
            rsCH.Fields("Field") = "ReqReleaseFromEngr"
            rsCH.Fields("OldValue") = .Fields("ReqReleaseFromEngr")
            rsCH.Fields("NewValue") = .Fields("Req'd Release from Engr")
            rsCH.Fields("RequestedBy") = "BAAN"
            If IsNull(.Fields("DateAssigned")) Then rsCH.Fields("ChangeAck") = -1
            rsCH.Update
            ' now make the change to the existing order
            .Edit
            .Fields("ReqReleaseFromEngr") = .Fields("Req'd Release from Engr")
            .Update
        End If
        .MoveNext
    Next
End With

Set rsOO = Nothing
Set rsCH = Nothing

        
     
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like `rsOO` is read-only.  Might want to share some details on that.

Comment: @TimWilliams How would I know if its read-only? The OpenOrdersOnOrderImportFile is a query which is what the rsOO is equal to, while the OrderChanges is a table. The query has two tables from which it is extracting records from essentially.

Comment: @TimWilliams The query only has some joins between two tables. Also i have taken the tables and anything associated with this code onto a different access db. I doubt that would cause any of the tables, queries, etc to be in read-only mode.